# Write multiple matches from regex to a file on a single line a certain way

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write multiple matches from regex to a file on a single line a certain way.

```
matches = re.findall(<form>(.*?)</form>, line, re.DOTALL)
for form in matches:
  form = ("'" + form + "', ")
  f = open(new_file, 'a+')  
  f.write(form.rstrip('\n'), )
```

The above gives me this:

```
'form1', 'form2',....,'formN',
```

How can I have them enclosed in parentheses and no comma at the end like below?

```
('form1', 'form2',....,'formN')
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Missing quotes in your `findall`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
matches = re.findall(<form>(.*?)</form>, line, re.DOTALL)
if matches:
    f = open(new_file, 'a+')  
    f.write("('%s')" % "', '".join(matches))
    f.close()
```

Comment: How to enclosed each item in single or double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), `re.findall` returns "all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as **a list of strings**".

Thus,

```
myline = "("
n = len( matches )
if ( n > 0 ) :
    myline = myline + "'" + matches[ 0 ] + "'" 
    for i in range( 1, n ) :
        myline = myline + ", '" + matches[ i ] + "'" 
myline = myline + ")"
# WRITE TO FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to python and just stuck in problem that i have script which can parse html lines using single regex .I want to parse using multiple words so that to get more appropriate results . my code is attached below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python file to monitor pastebin for pastes containing the passed regex

import sys
import time
import urllib
import re

f = open('sj1.txt', 'w')


# User-defined variables
time_between = 7       #Seconds between iterations (not including time used to fetch pages - setting below 5s may cause a pastebin IP block, too high may miss pastes)
error_on_cl_args = "Please provide a single regex search via the command line"   #Error to display if improper command line arguments are provided

# Check for command line argument (a single regex) 
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    search_term = sys.argv[1] and 
                  sys.argv[2] and 
                  sys.argv[3]
    print search_term
else:
    print error_on_cl_args
    exit()

iterater = 1

while(iterater):
    counter = 0

    print "Scanning pastebin - iteration " + str(iterater) + "..."

    #Open the recently posted pastes page
    try:
        url = urllib.urlopen("http://pastebin.com/archive")
        html = url.read()
        url.close()
        html_lines = html.split('\n')

        for line in html_lines:
            if counter < 308:
        #print line
                if re.search(r'<td><img src="/i/t.gif"  class="i_p0" alt="" /><a href="/[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}">.*</a></td>', line ):
            #print 'I am here'
                    link_id = line[61:69]
                    print link_id


                    #Begin loading of raw paste text
                    url_2 = urllib.urlopen("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=" + link_id)
                    raw_text = url_2.read()
            #print raw_text
                    url_2.close()

                    #if search_term in raw_text:
                    if re.search(r''+search_term, raw_text):
            print >> f, "FOUND " + search_term + " in http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=" + link_id


                    counter += 1
    except(IOError):
        print "Network error - are `enter code here`you connected?"
    except:
        print "Fatal error! Exiting."
        exit()
    iterater =0

    time.sleep(time_between)
```